# [flow]Multiple type check

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I use flowType to write express router code, and let flow to check the req.body data, body data have multiple type, such as UserData(bbb type) or LoginData(ccc type). But when the body transform data to function, flow always says something wrong. Is there any good idea to support body have multiple type check? Here is a demo wrong code.

```js
/* @flow */

declare type ccc = {
  ccc: string;
}

declare type bbb = {
  bbb: string;
}

declare type aaa = {
  body: bbb | ccc
}

function test(aaa: aaa) {
  const body = aaa.body

  test2(body)
}

function test2(body: ccc): string {
  return body['ccc']
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for someone to quickly help you if you edited your question to include the full error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The error

Here's the error you get when running the supplied code with `flow`:

```
 34:   test2(body)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^ function call
 37: function test2(body: ccc): string {
                          ^^^ property `ccc`. Property not found in
 34:   test2(body)
             ^^^^ object type
```

### The solution

The main issue here is `test2`. `aaa` can have a `body` value of either the `bbb` or the `ccc` type, which means that when you call

```
const body = aaa.body

  test2(body)
```

`body` can either be a match for type `bbb` or for type `ccc`, we don't know. Meanwhile, `test2` explicitly only accepts an argument of type `ccc`. Flow is seeing the possibility for `bbb` type to be passed, which will of course, not have the `ccc` property. At least one solution is to make the following change:

```
function test2(body: bbb | ccc): string {
  if (typeof body.ccc === 'string') {
    return body.ccc
  }

  return ''
}
```

We need `bbb | ccc` because it can in fact be either option. Next, we need the `typeof` check to ensure that we don't return `undefined` in the case where we passed in a `bbb` type. This removes the error.